# Totally disconnected implies base of closed sets?

Tags: general-topology, examples-counterexamples, connectedness

Any $\ T_0$ space that has a base consisting of closed (hence clopen) sets is totally disconnected.  Does a totally disconnected space necessarily have a base consisting of closed sets?

Comment: I think the converse is true if you add in "locally compact Hausdorff".

Comment: Willard's *General Topology* has one counterexample in exercise 29B. See [here](http://books.google.com/books?id=-o8xJQ7Ag2cC&pg=PA214#v=onepage&q&f=false). There are others; c.f. *Counterexamples in Topology* Steen and Seebach.

Comment: For the case that $X$ is compact, the result mentioned by Dylan is shown in this interesting blog post: [Thoughts about connectedness (Totally disconnected spaces)](http://drexel28.wordpress.com/2010/03/28/thoughts-about-connectedness-totally-disconnected-spaces/).

Answer (score 6):

Several examples of this kind are mentioned at standard places where to look for counterexamples in general topology.

Wikipedia article on [totally disconnected spaces](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Totally_disconnected) mentions [Erdős space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erd%C5%91s_space).
The same space is also mentioned as Example 6.2.19 in Ryszard Engelking: **General Topology**, Heldermann Verlag, Berlin, 1989. The proof I give bellow is essentially the same as in Engelking's book.

If we look at Steen-Seebach: [Counterexamples in Topology](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Counterexamples_in_Topology) we
find out from [Figure 9, p. 32](http://books.google.com/books?id=DkEuGkOtSrUC&pg=PA32) that further examples of $T_2$-spaces, which are totally disconnected but not [zero-dimensional](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-dimensional_space) should be Examples 72 (Rational extension in the plane), 79 (Irregular lattice topology), 113 (Strong ultrafilter topology), 127 (Roy's lattice subspace), 129 ([Knaster–Kuratowski fan](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knaster%E2%80%93Kuratowski_fan) a.k.a. [Cantor's teepe](http://books.google.com/books?id=DkEuGkOtSrUC&pg=PA145)).

Several examples can be found in [pi-base](https://topology.pi-base.org/spaces?q=Totally%20Disconnected%2B%7EZero%20Dimensional).

---

**Erdős space**

$\newcommand{\ve}{\varepsilon}\newcommand{\norm}[1]{\lVert{#1}\rVert}$Let us consider the space $$X=\ell_2\cap \mathbb Q^{\mathbb N}=\{(x_i); \sum {x_i}^2<\infty, (\forall i) x_i\in\mathbb Q\}$$ of all sequences of rational numbers which belong to $\ell_2$. We endow this space with the metric derived from the usual $\ell_2$ norm, i.e.
$$d(x,y)=\norm{x-y}_2 = \sqrt{\sum (x_i-y_i)^2}.$$

*Erdős space is totally disconnected:* If $a\ne b$ then we have at least one coordinate such that $a_i\ne b_i$. W.l.o.g. we assume $a_i<b_i$.
We choose an arbitrary irrational number $z$ such that $a_i<z<b_i$. The sets $U_{i,z}=\{x\in X; x_i<z\}$ and $V_{i,z}$ are open, disjoint and their union is the whole space $X$. (For any $x\in U_{i,z}$  and $\ve<z-x_i$ the $\ve$-ball around $x$ is a subset of $U_{i,z}$. The same argument shows that $V_{i,z}$ is open.) So we have found two clopen subset of $X$ such that one of them contains $a$ and the other one contains $b$. Therefore the connected components of $X$ are singletons, i.e. it is totally disconnected.

*Erdős space is not zero-dimensional:* Let $V=B(0,1)=\{x\in X; \norm{x}_2\le 1\}$. We will try to show that no open neighborhood $U$ of $0$ such that $U\subseteq V$ is clopen.

By induction we define a sequence $(a_k)$ of rationals such that for the sequence given by
$$x_k=(a_1,\dots,a_k,0,0,\dots)$$
we have $x_k\in U$ and $d(x_k,X\setminus U)\le\frac1k$.

For $k=1$ we can choose $a_1=0$.

If $a_1,\dots,a_{k-1}$ are already chosen, we consider the numbers $\frac i{k}$, $i=0,\dots,k$ as possible candidates for $a_k$. If we choose $a_k=\frac ik$ in a such way that $(a_1,\dots,a_{k-1},\frac ik,0,0,\dots)\in U$ and $(a_1,\dots,a_{k-1},\frac {i+1}k,0,0,\dots)\notin U$ then it is clear that $x_k\in U$ and $d(x_k,X\setminus U)\le\frac1k$.

Now let $x=(a_k)$. Since $\norm{x_k}_2^2 = \sum_{i=1}^k a_i^2 < 1$, we have that $\sum_{i=1}^\infty a_i^2 \le 1$ and $x\in X$.

We also see that the sequence $x_k$ converges to $x$, and thus $x\in \overline U$.

The condition $d(x_k,X\setminus U)\le\frac1k$ implies that there is a sequence $(v_k)$ of elements of  $X\setminus U$ such that $d(x_k,v_k)\le\frac1k$. Since $x_k\to x$, we see that also $v_k\to x$ and thus $x\in\overline{X\setminus U}$.

We have shown that $\overline U \cap \overline{X\setminus U}\ne\emptyset$, therefore $U$ cannot be clopen. $\hspace{2cm}\square$

For the origin of this example, I quote from Engelking's book:

> Example 6.2.19 was described in Erdős' paper [1940] (the first example of a separable metric space with similar properties was defined by Sierpinski in [1921]; Sierpinski's space is, moreover, completely metrizable).

- Erdős, P.: The dimension of the rational points in Hilbert space, Ann. Math. 41 (1940), 734-736. [jstor](http://www.jstor.org/stable/1968851) [renyi.hu](http://www.renyi.hu/%7Ep_erdos/1940-11.pdf)
- Sierpinski, W.: Sur les ensembles connexes et non connexes, Fund. Math. 2 (1921), 81-95. [matwbn](http://matwbn.icm.edu.pl/ksiazki/fm/fm2/fm2111.pdf)

Comment: @Thomas Thanks for noticing the typos, I've corrected these two.

Comment: Sure. +1 for a nice answer.