# Property between totally disconnected and zero dimensional

Tags: general-topology, connectedness

Assume all spaces are Hausdorff.

Definitions:

$X$ is *totally disconnected* if the only nonempty connected subsets of $X$ are singletons.

$X$ is *zero dimensional* if it has a base of clopen sets.

Now consider the following:

> A) $X$ is zero dimensional,
>
> B) for any $p\neq q\in X$ there exists a clopen set containing $p$
>   missing $q$ (the quasicomponents of $X$ are singletons),
>
> C) $X$ is totally disconnected (the components of $X$ are singletons)

It is clear to me that $A\Rightarrow B\Rightarrow C$, and I know that $A$ and $C$ are not equivalent.

Question: Is $B$ equivalent to either $A$ or $C$ ?  I think that $B\Leftrightarrow C$ if $X$ is compact since in this case quasicomponents are connected, but I'm not sure in general.

Edit: I am really interested in knowing if $B$ is strictly weaker than $A$, even for normal spaces.

Comment: Property (B) is called *totally separated* in Steen & Seebach.  Note that (A) zero dimensional implies (B) totally separated only for $T_0$ spaces.  For example, a space with the indiscrete topology is zero-dimensional, but not totally separated (since not even $T_1$).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No two of the three properties are equivalent for Hausdorff spaces in general. In [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/151954/12042) Martin Sleziak gives a proof that the [Erdős space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erd%C5%91s_space) $\ell^2\cap\Bbb Q^\omega$, the space of square-summable sequence of rational numbers, has (B) but not (A). The space obtained by removing the dispersion point $p=\left\langle\frac12,\frac12\right\rangle$ from the [Knaster-Kuratowski fan](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knaster%E2%80%93Kuratowski_fan) has (C) but not (B): its quasicomponents are the segments $L_c\setminus\{p\}$ for $c\in C$, the middle-thirds Cantor set.

Comment: Thanks.  I should have considered your second example.  I am not at all familiar with the Erdos space.

Comment: @ForeverMozart: You’re welcome. I confess that I’d completely forgotten about the Erdős space until I went digging a bit.