# A Property of Totally Disconnected Space

Tags: general-topology, connectedness

On pg. 4 of [this](https://www.math.ucdavis.edu/~osserman/classes/250C/notes/profinite.pdf) article on profinite groups is defined the following:

> A topological space $X$ is said to be **totally disconnected** if each connected component of $X$ is a singleton.

Then the author remarks that a space $X$ is totally disconnected if and only if for any two distinct points in $X$, there is a closed and open subset of $X$ which contains one of the points but not the other.

I am unable to show this. One direction is trivial. But I am not able to conclude from the definition of total disconnectedness that one can "separate any two points by a disconnection."

Comment: I believe this is false in general, the Knaster-Kuratowski fan (minus the top) is a counterexample, I believe. The fact *is* true for compact or locally compact Hausdorff spaces.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The statement is false in general. Two points of $X$ are in the same *quasicomponent* if there is no clopen set in $X$ containing exactly one of them. Thus, the **quasicomponents** are singletons if for any two points there is a clopen set containing exactly one of them. The component of a point is always a subset of the quasicomponent of the point, but the two need not be equal. They are always equal in compact Hausdorff spaces; [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/610578/12042) and [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/11412/any-two-points-in-a-stone-space-can-be-disconnected-by-clopen-sets/11423#11423) contain proofs. In [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1884559/12042) I gave an example of a space in which they are not equal.

Comment: Very interesting. I observed the same statement (regarding equivalence) on many web pages. Do you know if this slightly weaker disconnection property has a name?

Comment: @AfterMath: The property that distinct points can be separated by a clopen set, a sort of Hausdorff-like counterpart of zero-dimensionality? No, I don’t think that I’ve ever seen it given a name.

Comment: @AfterMath: Such spaces are called [totally separated](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Definition:Totally_Separated_Space). Sadly, there is inconsistent terminology in the literature. For instance, Engelking in "General Topology" calls a space "totally disconnected" if it is totally separated  and if a space is totally disconnected (in the standard sense), he calls it "hereditarily disconnected."

Comment: Incidentally, you gave another example in your earlier answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1078124/property-between-totally-disconnected-and-zero-dimensional).