# Pugh's definition of 'totally disconnected space'

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

In Pugh's text Real Mathematical Analysis page 105, he defines a 'totally disconnected space' as follows:

> A metric space $M$ is totally disconnected if each point $p ∈ M$ has arbitrarily small clopen neighborhoods. 
>   That is, given $\epsilon > 0, p ∈ M$, there exists a clopen set $U$ such that
>   $p ∈ U ⊂ M_{\epsilon}(p)$

Edit: $M_{\epsilon}(p)$ means 'an open ball of radius $\epsilon$ around p'

The usual definition of a totally disconnected space is one where the singletons are the only connected subspaces.

I can see how Pugh's definition implies the usual one, but not the other way around. There may be a contrived example where in fact the clopen subsets are ugly enough that they allow for total disconnectedness yet there aren't any clopen sets contained in a ball of radius $\epsilon$.

I can't find a counterexample either since all the metric spaces I've worked with thus far are 'nice'.

So my question is - with regards to metric spaces, are these definitions equivalent?

Comment: Could you please clarify what $M_\epsilon(p)$ means?

Comment: edited: it's an open ball of radius epsilon around p

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/142070/totally-disconnected-implies-base-of-closed-sets/151954#151954

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Pugh's notion is normally called $0$-dimensional (clopen base) and totally disconnected is usually reserved for spaces whose components are singletons.

A (separable metric) space where these notions differ is [Erdős space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erd%C5%91s_space), which is not zero-dimensional (but $1$-dimensional) but totally disconnected. There are even infinite-dimensional Polish spaces that are totally disconnected (!). In locally compact spaces the notions do coincide, but too bad that Pugh uses non-standard terminology.

Comment: could you provide a hint about how to prove that Pugh's definition implies the usual definition? Thanks!

Comment: @KarthikKannan if a component would have two distinct points there’d be a clopen set separating making the component disconnected (contradiction).

Comment: I am extremely sorry, I meant the other way around i.e. usual definition implies Pugh's definition. Like the OP I couldn't figure the proof of this direction. Thank you.

Comment: @KarthikKannan I gave a metric counterexample, so you cannot show the other way around because it's false.

Comment: Thank you very much. I understood your point.